# Adding New Image to Asset Path Then Rails 5 Won't Load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails app in development (localhost) environment with some images in assets path. Every time I add another image (copying it to asset path) and then run the server, the page won't load.

It happens for no reason, then I tried to run `rake assets:precompile`. It takes around 30 mins to finish the process. It works again.

Now that I want to add another new image to asset folder, then the server won't run again. So I have to run again the precompile command to make it work again.

It is unusual because before if I add new image to asset folder, I don't have to run precompile command.

I also noticed that when running the command, it created new folder in public folder.

Is it or bug on Rails 5 or something else? Thank you.

---

UPDATE

There is no error message, but here's the chronology:

1. I copy new image to asset folder in rails app
2. I run the server `rails server`
3. I open `localhost:3000` in the browser
4. The page won't load
5. Here is the log:

   ```
   => Booting Puma
   => Rails 5.0.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
   => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
   Puma starting in single mode...
   Version 3.7.1 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Snowy Sagebrush
   Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
   Environment: development
   Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
   Use Ctrl-C to stop
   Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2018-01-24 00:19:01 +0700
     ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.6ms)  SELECT 
   "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
   Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
     Rendering pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application
   Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2018-01-24 00:19:04 +0700
   Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
     Rendering pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application
   ^CExiting
     Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (409487.0ms)
     Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (413206.1ms)
   Completed 401 Unauthorized in 409506ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
   ```

Then I tried to troubleshoot the issue by running `rake assets:precompile`, then I restart the server and the page loaded properly.

But whenever I add another image to assets folder, I have to run precompile command which takes around 30 mins to finish (very unusual, I never run precompile command before and my app worked just fine in the past)

I also found that by running the precompile command created a new folder in public directory which is never happened to me before.

---

UPDATE #2

Here is my `assets.rb` looks like:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Add additional assets to the asset load path
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error you are getting when you copy a new image and run server?

Comment: @AneesMuhammed I updated the post to show you the error

Comment: Where do you place your images and how do your `assets.rb` look? (placed in config/).

Comment: I put my images in app/assets/ and from there, there are several subfolders to categorize the images. I updated the question with my assets.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Never put your image to `apps/assets/images/` as it will need to compile the image to set to public, all you need to do is to move all the images to `public/` and then create new subfolder called `assets/` or something you wish to use.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me though. All the documentation says that they should load automatically as long as long as they're namespaced.